# Platform specific files file.ios.js | file.android.js not detected correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native, import

According to the [react native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code) "React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android. extension and load the relevant platform file when required from other components". I am trying to import a different **store** for each of the platform `some.store.ios.js` and `some.store.android.js` and instantiate it inside a single shared component `my.component.js`.

**some.store.android.js**

```
const SomeStore = class {
    consturctor() {
        console.log('Android')
    }
}
export default SomeStore
```

**some.store.ios.js**

```
const SomeStore = class {
    consturctor() {
        console.log('IOS')
    }
}
export default SomeStore
```

**my.component.js** functional component

```
import SomeStore from 'stores/some.store'
const MyComponent = observer(() => {
    [someStore]= useState(() => new SomeStore())
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the log **IOS** for both of the platforms. I have tested on real mobile devices.

The workaround that I am currently using is exporting stores with different names, importing both and selecting the needed on inside the component:

```
import SomeStoreAndroid from 'stores/some.store.android'
import SomeStoreIOS from 'stores/some.store.ios'

...

if(Platform.OS === "android") {
    [someStore]= useState(() => new SomeStoreAndroid())
} else {
    [someStore]= useState(() => new SomeStoreIOS())
}
```

But this shouldn't be needed, why doesn't the first (the natural) method work?

Comment: is there some typo? `some.store.andoird.js` in file name?

Comment: Only in the question, the project doesn't have the typo, thank you I have updated the question